# Why some full screen website width do not match my screen width?

Tags: html, css, width

I use a 1920px wide screen. But when I inspect the html tag with chrome devtools on websites such as firebase or facebook messenger, this is what I see :

[image: Example 2]

But these websites appear fullscreen, so I expected them to match my screen width.

Why is there a difference between my screen width (1920px) and the html tag width (1440px) and how to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a fixed width, and stretch to fit the screen?

Comment: It's a behavior I observe on at least 3 well-designed websites, I just wonder how they do it.

Comment: The example you gave, https://console.firebase.google.com has no width (so width:auto by default) on the html tag, so it's calculating your screen at 1440px... Check the res of your display and how it's set up. If you're on a Mac go into your system preferences and check how your scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have setup a DPI scaling on your PC or have the zoom level in your browser to something higher than 100%

Comment: No, I want my page to be full screen but elements would be sized as it the screen was 1440 px wide. For example if I set a div's width to 720px, it should take half of the screen no matter the user's screen size. That's the behavior I observe on the websites I mentioned.

Comment: I'm still not clear exactly what you want to achieve... Could you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of the body of your HTML to a fixed width of 1440px, it will be 1440px even if the user screen is bigger or smaller than this. What you can do is set width to `width: 100%;` and a `max-width: 1440px`. That would make the size of the body to be the size of the screen if the screen is smaller than 1440px and 1440px if the screen is larger or equals to 1440px.

If I understood correctly what you are asking, you have a sidebar menu and a dashboard that needs to fullfill the screen. In that case, you could do:

```
.side-menu {
  width: 20%;
}

.dashboard {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .side-menu {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

Using [media-query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) makes you set different CSS properties for the elements in your HTML, depending, in this example, of the screen size. What I did: if the screen size is smaller than 1440px, the sidebar fills 20% of it and the dashboard fills 80%. If the screen size is bigger or equals to 1500px (a little big bigger than the max-width of the dashboard, to fit the sidebar also), the dashboard stays at 1440px and the sidebar fills the rest of the screen width (`width: 100%` makes the sidebar takes all the width that is left of the body).

Obviously in bigger websites such as Facebook etc it's a much more complex thinking than just CSS, because they have to consider the data flow, the device the person is using and many other things.

Comment: Sorry that's not an answer to my problem ! In my case the page is fullscreen and chrome devtools displays a page width of 1440px whereas I use a 1920px wide screen. Check by yourself https://console.firebase.google.com/ for example